# How to convert the cp1251 values to utf8 in a select query from table with utf8 collation?

Tags: mysql

There's a column in a MySQL table with utf8 collation but there are a few values in it and there actual encoding is cp1251.

The problem is that the values in the result of the select queries are not utf8 encoded.

I've tried the following but it didn't work:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(text USING cp1251) AS BINARY) USING utf8) FROM example
```

Does anyone know a way to convert the cp1251 values to utf8 in my select query?

Comment: So what is the problem? What is the one you are trying, the one you need and what error/problem you have? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: OK I'll edit the question.